# How to print the formatted Data on webpage submitted using ckeditor as html from database?

Tags: jquery, jsp, ckeditor

I am submitting into database from ckEditor using:

`CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement().document.getBody().getText();`

My data is saving in the database as html code perfectly like:

`<ol>
 <li>test text</li> 
</ol>`

When I am trying to retrieve that back from the database it is showing the html tags just the way it is saved instead of the ordered list. The same is happening with other formattings as well.

I tried using `getData()` as well but it is also resulting in the same.

For submitting the value:

> var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('addque', 
>               {
>
> ```
>           focus: onFocus,
>           blur: onBlur,
>           toolbar : [
>                       ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print',> 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
>                       ['Undo','Redo'],
>                       ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
>                       ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
>                       ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
>                       ['Link','Unlink','Anchor', 'Image', 'Smiley'],
>                       ['Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar'],
>                       ['Format','BGColor']
>           ],
>           width: "80em",
>           height: "7em",
>           enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
>           shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P            });
>       editor.on("instanceReady", function(){
>           this.document.on("keyup", fe_jq);
>       });             editor.on('blur', function(){
>           modified = true;
>           CKEDITOR.instances.addque.updateElement().document.getBody().getText();
>       });
>       function fe_jq()
>           {
>               var len = CKEDITOR.instances.addque.document.getBody().getText();
>               var textLen = len.length;
>                               if(textLen > 30){
>                   alert(len); 
>               }       
>           }
> ```

For retreiving:

`Iterator iterator = queList.iterator();

```
                    int iRow = 1;
                    boolean f = false;
                    while(iterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        String queString = (String)iterator.next();
                                                    String que = queArray[1];}
```

`

<%=que%>

<%=que%> is inside the pre tag which is not getting printed here.

---

The problem got half solved. I had put the output string inside the pre & xmp tag earlier. So putting the string in div tag solved the problem.

The problem still persisting is that when I insert the data in an ordered list then the output is not a list. Its just showing the data in two different lines.

Comment: How do you output the retreived code on your webpage?

Comment: I am fetching the String from database and printing it inside a pre tag.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code. Otherwise it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Where is the code which outputs the text on the webpage?